# Payload from a defined list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pretty new to python and I am trying to create a script that will pull data from a ticketing platform.

I got the list of agents and their ids but when I try to pull the data it's giving me this error:

KeyError: 'data'

Is there a way for me to have the parameter "agents": to automatically update using the agent_id list?

Here is the code, I removed the links and the API key for privacy reasons:

```
import requests
import json
from cgitb import text
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl
import requests
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
#Agents list
agents_list = ["Agent1", "Agent2", "Agent3"]
agent_id = []
agents_names = []

today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)

start_date = str(yesterday)
end_date = str(yesterday)

def extragere_date_agenti():
    url = "https://x.gorgias.com/api/users?limit=100&order_by=name%3Aasc&roles=agent&roles=admin"

    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "authorization": "Basic"
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    text_name_id = json.loads(response.text)
    for names in text_name_id["data"]:
        agent_name = names["firstname"]
        agents_id = names["id"]
        if agent_name in agents_list:
            agents_names.append(agent_name)
            agent_id.append(agents_id)
extragere_date_agenti()

def extragere_numere():
    url = "https://x.gorgias.com/api/stats/total-messages-sent"

    payload = {"filters": {
            "period": {
                "start_datetime": start_date + "T00:00:00-05:00",
                "end_datetime": end_date + "T23:59:59-05:00"
            },
            "agents": [agent_id], #This is the value that I want to modify
            "channels": ["email"]
        }}
    headers = {   
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": "Basic"
    }
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
    text_numere = json.loads(response.text)
    numere_finale = text_numere["data"]["data"]["value"]
    print(numere_finale)
```

I've tried to do a for loop but it's giving me the same error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your Error:

`KeyError: 'data'`

Means that in `text_name_id` is no Key named "data".

Difficult to tell you how to fix it without any more info...

Are you sure, that request returns a positiv status?? I see no ErrorHandling, `if respone.status_code == 200:` should be enough to check.

Are you sure that the response json has a Key named "data"? Try this to set a default if key is missing:

`text_name_id.get("data", [{"firstname": "error", "id": 0}])`

--- Edit ---

Okay, is that the right one I don't see a "id" or "firstname" key. But if it is the right JSON, than you can't iterate over dict like you did in Python.
To do so you would want to do this:

```
for key, value in text_name_id['data']['data'].items():
    ...
```

Comment: thank you for your response, the code works and I am able to get the required data if, for example I have the attribute set as "agents": [agent_id[0]]

What I'm trying to do is to automatically change the [0] to include all of the values from that list

Comment: Could you post the response JSON (or a part of it). Otherwise it is not really possible to help you here..

Comment: @Beta94 Sure thing. Here it is:

'''
{"data": {"data": {"name": "total_messages_sent", "type": "number", "value": 88, "delta": 100}}, "meta": {"end_datetime": "2022-10-10T23:59:59-05:00", "previous_end_datetime": "2022-10-09T23:59:59-05:00", "previous_start_datetime": "2022-10-09T00:00:00-05:00", "start_datetime": "2022-10-10T00:00:00-05:00"}}
'''

Comment: Okay, is that the right one I don't see a "id" or "firstname" key. But if it is the right JSON, than you can't iterate over dict like you did in Python.
To do so you would want to do this:

for key, value in text_name_id['data']['data'].items():
    ...

Answer (score 0):

First, add the condition to check the response status code
Also, add another condition to prevent this type of key error:

`if "data" in text_name_id:`

Comment: Found another way to partially fix the error. I've added "agents":[agent_id[i]]

And added the following while loop at the end:

while i < len(agent_id):
    print(numere_finale)
    i = i +1 

But this shows me the number for the first agent only, 4 times.